# Can't find resource for bundle using Push SDK low level APIs

Tags: blackberry

I am using the following post as a guide - http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Push-SDK-using-low-level-APIs/td-p/1173007.

The class Push.java compiles OK.  But when I try to run it (java Push), I am getting the following error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle    java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key use.public.push
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:374)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:334)
        at net.rim.pushsdk.commons.DefaultPropertyStore.getProperty(DefaultPropertyStore.java:62)
        at net.rim.pushsdk.commons.PropertyStore.getBooleanProperty(PropertyStore.java:90)
        at net.rim.pushsdk.commons.PushSDKPropertiesImpl.isUsingPublicPush(PushSDKPropertiesImpl.java:345)
        at net.rim.pushsdk.pap.control.PapControl.isUsingPublicPush(PapControl.java:176)
        at net.rim.pushsdk.pap.PapServiceImpl.push(PapServiceImpl.java:90)
        at Push.main(Push.java:46)
nattyp@arya:~/projects/push/test$
```

My directoy listing is

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 nattyp nattyp  4096 Aug 25  2007 org
drwxr-xr-x 3 nattyp nattyp  4096 Apr 29  2011 net
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp 12614 Jun 22 11:07 PushSDK.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp   741 Jun 22 11:07 pushsdk-pap-context.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp  1472 Jun 22 11:07 pushsdk-commons-context.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp  8483 Jun 22 11:07 pap_2.1.dtd
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp  8417 Jun 22 11:07 pap_2.0.dtd
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp  2260 Jun 22 11:07 log4j.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp  2646 Jun 22 12:17 Push.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 nattyp nattyp  2257 Jun 22 12:28 Push.java
 The org and net directories are the jar extract from pap-1.1.0.16.jar and commons-pushsdk-1.1.0.16.jar.
```

What am I missing?